# backbone rendering subview inside subview

Tags: backbone.js

I have a peopleview which renders personViews which renders subviews. Peopleview is rendered and personviews but subviews are not. Debugging shows that it goes to subview but it is not rendered.

peopleview:

```
    render:function () {
        $("#page").html(compiledTemplate);
        _.each(personViewPointers, function (item) {
            $(".people-collection").append(item.render().el)
        });
        return this
    }
```

personview rendeting subviews. Renders OK but subviews are not rendered.

```
    render:function () {
        var data = {
            model:this.model,
            _:_
        };
        this.$el.html(compiledTemplate(data))
        this.addAllSubViews()
        var self = this
        _.each(subviews, function (item) {
            self.$el.append(item.render().el)
        });
        return this
    }
```

subview which does not render.

```
    render:function () {
        this.$el.html(compiledTemplate)
        return this
    }
```

Comment: Is subview's render actually called? Have you tried to put a breakpoint on that?

Comment: Yes it is. I made a simple template just to test and console.log($(this.el)) after this.$el.html(compiledTemplate) gives "<div>test</div>". This is actually called now twice, there is two subviews..

Comment: Where does `subviews` come from? How about `personViewPointers`? And shouldn't `$("#page").html(compiledTemplate);` be `$("#page").html(compiledTemplate());`? `compiledTemplate` would presumably be a function that returns some HTML rather than HTML itself.

Comment: subviews are added from collection at personview: this.collection.each(this.addOne) ... subviews[model.id] = new personbillableitemview({model:model}). And personViewPointers are added from peopleViews collection same way. compiledTemplate comes with AMD using text plugin: define([
    'Appregistry',
'collections/admin/peopleCollection',
'views/admin/personView',
'text!templates/admin/people/people.html',
'models/admin/personDtoModel'
], function (Appregistry, peopleCollection, personView, peopleTemplate, personDtoModel). I tried this: $("#page").html(compiledTemplate()) not working

Answer (score 0):

**Tip**

You're using `$("#page")` and `$(".people-collection")` which couples the personview directly to the DOM.

I recommend using `this.$el`and `this.$(".people-collection")` instead:

```
render:function () {
    this.$el.html(compiledTemplate);
    _.each(personViewPointers, function (item) {
        this.$(".people-collection").append(item.render().el)
    }, this);
    return this
}
```

and pass the #page element in the constructor:

```
var pv = new PersonView({el: '#page'});
```

But once you've used `new PersonView({el: '#page'})` you can't really use the '#page' for anything else, the View has bound events etc to the element. So it's even better to add it as an element:

```
var pv = new PersonView();
$('#page').empty();
$('#page').append(pv.render().this);
```

Which allows to to remove `pv.remove()` and replace the element with another view.

Comment: I tried this: _.each(subviews, function (item) {
                this.$el.append(item.render().el)
                this.$el.append("rendered")
            }, this); on personView. This "rendered" is rendered now. These subviews are still not rendered, any ideas?

Comment: Got this littlebit futher. The problem seems to be these subviewpointers. when first person view with 2 -subviews is rendered, everything seems to be ok. Next person view without any subviews removes all subviews including previously added.

Comment: Your current implementation does complicates using multiple instances of PersonView. I've added a "add it as an element" section to my answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. With short testing all bindings were binded from last model, so need to investigate more of this approach of passing el element to new view. I used "this" like you succested and it seems to work(renders to page), but renders all these viewpointers to every personviews so I added checking: _.each(subviews, function (item) {
               if(item.model.get("person").id == self.model.id){
                   self.$el.find(".section-content").append(item.render().el)
               }
            });. This feels like hack, need to find better way.

Comment: Don't use a global variable (personViewPointers) for the subviews, but use an instance variable `this.personViewPointers` which you'll create in the initialize method: `this.personViewPointers = [];`